# Returning values from a SQL Server stored procedure?

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, vb6

I want to know whether there is any way besides the `OUT` parameter to get data from stored procedure into C# code.

Today my colleague told me that all `select` queries and the `OUT` parameters in a stored procedure are returned to the C# code. Is this correct? If yes, then how do I choose which results should be returned?

Is the answer same in case of VB6 code instead of c#?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Do you want a single value? or multiple values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can return values back to your application from a SP using either **OUT** parameters or a **SELECT** within the SP.

The **OUT** parameters are generally used for single values. The **SELECT** can be used for returning rows of results. A combination of both can be used in many different variations, such as the SP will return rows and a status OUT parameter can indicate row count or existence of the requested data.

```
CREATE PROC usp_MySpecialSP
  @conditionValue INT, @SPStatus INT OUT
AS
  IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE column1=conditionValue)
  BEGIN
    SELECT @SPStatus=COUNT(*) FROM TableName WHERE column1=conditionValue
    SELECT Column2, Column3, Column4 FROM TableName WHERE column1=conditionValue
  END
  ELSE
  BEGIN
    SELECT @SPStatus=0
  END
GO
```

Here you can pickup values if the *m_SPStatusReturned>0*.

Check out below MSDN article how to pick up returned rows from SP
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d7125bke.aspx

or a single value using SELECT
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/37hwc7kt.aspx

Comment: 1st question: what is m_SPStatusReturned>0? Do you mean SPStatus>0?

Comment: 2nd question: What if there are multiple selects queries, then, do all get passed on to the c#.net??

Comment: 3rd question: You have typed --> SELECT @SPStatus=0, should'nt it be SET @SPStatus=0??

Comment: 4rth question: Is the answer same in case of VB6 code instead of c#.net?

Comment: Firstly sorry for the delayed answer. 1st Answer: m_SPStatusReturned is the C# variable that captures the value of the OUT parameter in the procedure. @SPStatus is the variable in the procedure in MSSQL

Comment: 2nd Answer: You will need to UNION them all together to form a single result. I've never tried multiple seperate SELECT queries in a procedure, so can't tell you what exactly you will get in your C# application.

Comment: 3rd Answer: AFAIK, SET in MSSQL is used only to store a static values into a variable. SELECT can also do the same, but SELECT can also store the result of an expression in the variable, which SET cannot do.

Comment: 4th Answer: The Stored Procedure will remain the same. But yes the application (VB6/C#/VB.NET/Java) code will change as per their respective syntax.

Comment: In your SQL script, suppose if there was a query like SELECT tempvar1,tempvar2 from sometable. and tempvar1 and 2 are not output parameters but INT declared within SP, then will the result be returned?

Comment: Yes. The values of tempvar1 and tempvar2 will be returned to the calling function in the application. If you set the OUTPUT variable and then SELECT tempvar1, tempvar2 [FROM <sometable>] then you can get the output value as well as return values in the application.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is correct - and the way you handle this is:

- to get an `OUT` parameter, you need define a `SqlParameter` on your `SqlCommand` with `ParameterDirection.Output`
- to get the result set of the `SELECT` in a stored procedure, you need to use a `SqlDataReader` or a `SqlDataAdapter` to get the results (as if you execute an inline SQL `SELECT` query)
- and there's actually a third way : the `RETURN` keyword inside a stored procedure - typically used to return a numeric status value. You can capture that by using a `SqlParameter` with a value of `ParameterDirection.ReturnValue`